# How to create a new data frame with original data separated by ; and with different counts per category?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a table with the following format.

```
df1 <- data.frame (A=c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"),
                   B=c("111; 222", "333", "444; 555; 666; 777", "888; 999"))

    A                  B
1 aaa           111; 222
2 bbb                333
3 ccc 444; 555; 666; 777
4 ddd           888; 999
```

I want to have a dataframe like this:

```
aaa 111
aaa 222
bbb 333
ccc 444
ccc 555
ccc 666
ccc 777
ddd 888
ddd 999
```

I found a wonderful solution to convert a similar list to dataframe in previous Stack Overflow questions.  However, it is difficult for me to convert it from a dataframe with multiple entries.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple base R solution (explanation below):

```
spl <- with(df1, strsplit(as.charcter(B), split = "; ", fixed = TRUE))
lens <- sapply(spl, length)
out <- with(df1, data.frame(A = rep(A, lens), B = unlist(spl)))
```

Which gives us:

```
R> out
    A   B
1 aaa 111
2 aaa 222
3 bbb 333
4 ccc 444
5 ccc 555
6 ccc 666
7 ccc 777
8 ddd 888
9 ddd 999
```

What is the code doing? Line 1:

```
spl <- with(df1, strsplit(as.character(B), split = "; ", fixed = TRUE))
```

breaks apart each of the strings in `B` using `"; "` as the characters to split on. We use `fixed = TRUE` (as suggested by **@Marek** in the comments) to speed up the matching and splitting as in this case we do not need to match using a regular expression, we simply want to match on the stated string. This gives us a list with the various elements split out:

```
R> spl
[[1]]
[1] "111" "222"

[[2]]
[1] "333"

[[3]]
[1] "444" "555" "666" "777"

[[4]]
[1] "888" "999"
```

The next line simply counts how many elements there are in each component of the list `spl`

```
lens <- sapply(spl, length)
```

which gives us a vectors of lengths:

```
R> lens
[1] 2 1 4 2
```

The final line of the solution plugs the outputs from the two previous steps into a new data frame. The trick is to repeat each element of `df1$A` `lens` number of times; for which we use the `rep()` function. We also need to unwrap the list `spl` into a vector which we do with `unlist()`:

```
out <- with(df1, data.frame(A = rep(A, lens), B = unlist(spl)))
```

Comment: Like in Brandon answer: use `fixed=TRUE` argument of `strsplit` to speed up computetions.

Comment: @Marek Thanks for that pointer, hadn't really noticed that before. I'll edit it in to my answer for completeness.

Comment: @Brandon you know what they say about "old dogs and new tricks"? That fits me to a tee! ;-)

Comment: Though I do make exceptions for @hadley's code from time to time - it's just so damned useful!

Comment: Copy-pasting the above code yields: `Error in strsplit(B, split = "; ", fixed = TRUE) : non-character argument`. However, wrapping B in `as.character(B)` works. (R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance")

Comment: Thanks @PatrickT +1. That may have change in R since 2011 - it is as you say in 3.0-patched too. I'll edit the answer to include the info.

Answer (score 7):

Literally the same as step one in my answer to your previous question:

```
library(reshape)
x <- melt((strsplit(as.character(df1$B), "; ")))
x <- data.frame("A"=df1[x$L1,1],"B"=x$value)
```

Comment: In this case `fixed=TRUE` argument of `strsplit` speed up execution.